# How to pass props into a react-router with ReactJS (and react-router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this snippet of code that toggles between different components.
I would like to pass values down to the different components in an easy way, like this;

```
<Route path="student" component={Student} websocket={self.websocket}/>
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? I have looked at cloning classes etc, but I don't think those answers are "good enough" I guess. I haven't found a similar situation and hope someone can answer my question.

The code in "full";

```html
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="student" component={Student}/>
    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginForm}/>
    <Route path="oauth" component={Knapp}/>
  </Route>
</Router>, document.getElementById("container") );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
class Example extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        Checking props - {this.props.route.foo}
      </h1>
    );
  }

}

var routes = (
  <Route path="/" foo="bar" component={Example}/>
);
```

Also you can look [***here***](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/facebook/react/q/stackoverflow/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component) how to do it in another way

I hope it will help you
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion. I can't really make it work like this, not sure why, but every time I pass in an object or anything other than a string, I get "undefined" in the Student-component. I will however, look more into this. Thank you for  your answer.

Comment: In other words, your answer probably works for other people!